# Javascript separation and cropping and round digits

Tags: javascript, crop, digits

I have a problem with this short script. Script must show digits like this 10 987.23 or 10 987 (2 symbols after dot or not), but showing NaN. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
var dohzavershen = "10 987.23456457457"; // corrected
dohzavershen = dohzavershen.replace(/.+?(?=\D|$)/, 
  function(f) {
    return f.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)/g, "$1 ")
  ;}
);

document.write(Number(dohzavershen).toFixed(0));

<script>
```

Comment: You're converting a string into something that's not a valid representation of a number, and then trying to parse it into a number. That's why you're getting NaN.

Comment: @JLRishe but in this string is a digits (var dohzavershen = "10 987.2345789099888";

Comment: It's still not a valid number in JavaScript. Numbers can't have spaces in them. `Number("10 987.23456457457")` evaluates to `NaN`.

Comment: @SergNuvels valid numbers don't have blank spaces in JavaScript.

Comment: The approach you're trying to use doesn't make any sense. `toFixed()` returns a number represented as a series of digits with no separators, optionally followed by a decimal point and more digits. What you are trying to do is convert a string into the number format you want, then convert that into a number, and then call `.toFixed()` on that. There's no way that's going to work. You need to think up a different approach.

Comment: @JLRishe
Sorry i can't understang you, i'm not a pro. Can you show me an example or correct my code, please.

if code like this "document.write(dohzavershen);" , all work well but numbers are BIGGGGEST like 12334.3986539000900999

Comment: @AlessioCantarella thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dohzavershen = "10 987.23456457457"; // corrected

function formatter(n, k) {
   var split = n.split('.');
   if (split.length > 1) {
      split[split.length-1] = split[split.length-1].substring(0, k);
   }
   return k > 0 ? split.join('.') : split[0];
}

formatter(dohzavershen, 2)
```

Something like this might work. But note that this does not round off the number but just selects the first two digits after the decimal point. The k>0 is just to make sure you dont get a "1234.", you can handle it any which way you think is appropriate

Comment: thanks but didn't work. And round is important to me. thats a problem.. this full code """ var oriprice = $origprice;
 
 document.write(Number(oriprice).toFixed(0)); """ work perfect but don't rounded number..

Comment: i dont understand how to fix my problem(

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work ? and i thought the space between your numbers is important. With that in place trying to convert it to number will not work.

Comment: full code looks like <?php
    
 $resultoursalerealpricesum = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(order_price) from `tbl_orders` WHERE status='Завершен'");
    if ($topmenuZavershen!=0) { ?>
    
 <script>var x = "<?php echo mysql_result($resultoursalerealpricesum, 0);?>";x = x.replace(/.+?(?=\D|$)/, function(f) {return f.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)/g, "$1 ");});document.write(x);</script>
 
 <?php } ?>

Comment: I am just splitting the string with a '.' and joining it again by formatting it.
If you want it to be rounded of to zero decimal points just call 
formatter(yourvariable,0)